# Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have this error in my table and it do that my buton didnt appear in the index. Can you know why this happens?

[image]

I run this command but it dosent work: **npm run dev**

I see like this:

[image]

Comment: You have to define this in your webpack config (assuming your using webpack). Use `mix.sourceMaps()` and for vite use `build.sourcemap(true)`

Comment: That error (which is a warning and can typically be ignored) is not related to your button not appearing in the index. Your issue is likely different e.g. you use HTML in a place where HTML would get escaped